# Force TypeScript to type object literally

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a large constant JavaScript object. Something like this:

```js
const commonStyles = {
    fullContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    justifyEvenly: {
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    },
    widthBound: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: breakpoints.default,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    }
    (...there is more)
}
```

TypeScript automatically types all the CSS property texts ("flex-start", "space-evenly", etc.) as string, but I want them to be typed as literals.

```
// What I get
{
    fullContainer: {
        flex: number,
        alignItems: string,
        justifyContent: string,
    },
    ...
}
// What I want
{
    fullContainer: {
        flex: number,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    ...
}
```

I could manually annotate the type, of course. But the object here is very large (>50 entries and growing), so writing the complete type annotation would be very tedious.

My question: is there a way to make TypeScript automatically type the object as literally as possible?

Comment: Additional note: in the 'What I want' part, I'm OK with both `flex: number` and `flex: 1`.

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: You can use `as const` assertion. `const foo = { alignItems: 'stretch' } as const;`

Comment: `as const` is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) can be used to prevent literal types widening:

```
const commonStyles = {
    fullContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    justifyEvenly: {
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    },
    //...
} as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC29wGUoE8A2BTCMC8MA3gFAxkwBmArhhgMLhQCGAlmFgE4BcRp5-FbAA8eARgA0ffmSYYWAczABJKFngQeAcmgcsUYAAtNk6eQBWVaCwpoGYVfa2CsQgLTQmHKMakwAvibmllDWaACiAG5YYBhoPCSmZBZWNnYOUFoQAA5MwFiuWFExaD78Ab4A9BUAdLXEfjBMuKCQUADcQA)

> - no literal types widened
> - object literals get readonly properties
> - array literals become readonly tuples